# How to know if a function has an unspecified number of parameters (like in a variadic template or an ellipsis) in visual c++ code model?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

How to know if a function has an unspecified number of parameters (like in a variadic template or an ellipsis) in visual c++ code model?
For example, if the source code has:

```
template<class... Ts>
void func(Ts... v){ }
```

using (c# code) `VCCodeModel.Functions.Item("func").Parameters.Count` gives 1. So I can't think of a way to know that it is a variadic template.

Comment: Because of the syntax used in the function declaration? Can you please [edit] your question to give us some more details bout your problem?

Comment: have you tried inspecting the properties of `VCCodeModel.Functions.Item("func").Parameters[0]`?

Comment: Well, which property of VCCodeParameter will I check actually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `VCCodeParameter` object for a specific parameter.
If variadic template is used with that parameter, `VCCodeParameter.Name` will have a "..." in front of it. If an ellipsis is used, `VCCodeParameter.TypeString` will be "...". All parameters in the function can be checked in this manner to find out whether the function has an unspecified number of parameters.

Don't know if this technique will work for every case.